# InvalidAuthenticationInfo error while uploading dcument in Azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, api, rest, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload document in Azure blob storage through REST API but getting authentication error.

Sharing request header and url-

```
message = bytes(sas_token, 'utf-8')
secret = bytes(key, 'utf-8')
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
signature = str(signature)

header = {
           "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
           "x-ms-date":"Fri, 12 Mar 2021 23:39:12 GMT",
           "Content-Type": "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8" ,
           "Content-Length": "1048576",
           "x-ms-copy-source" : "" 
           "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
           "Authorization": "SharedKey myaccount:" + signature,
}

URL - "https://"+ account_name+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container_name+"/"+name

response- requests.put(url, headers=headers)
```

Response - <Response [400]>

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code><Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.`

Also I'm not sure how should I pass document if my document location is `OBJECT_LOCATION = "/home/meera/Downloads/download.pdf"`  I want to upload this download.pdf file in blob storage.

Documentation following - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` instead of storage account key for authorization. If that's the case, then you don't really need to compute the signature as the signature is already calculated in SAS.

Your code would be something like:

```
header = {
           "Content-Type": "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8" ,
           "Content-Length": "1048576",
           "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob"
}

URL - "https://"+ account_name+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container_name+"/"+name+"?"+sas_token

response- requests.put(url, headers=headers)
```

**UPDATE**

Please try this code.

```
account_name = "account-name"
container_name = "container-name"
name = "file-name.pdf"
sas_token = "?shared-access-signature-token"
filepath = "full path of the file-name.pdf"
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read() # Read whole file in the file_content string
headers = { "Content-Type": "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8", "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob" }
url = "https://"+ account_name+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container_name+"/"+name+sas_token
response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=file_content)
```

Comment: yes, I was using SAS. I tried your solution but that error is not fixed. Sharing the api response- `<Response [403]>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:e1a9cee9-101e-0033-175a-178d04000000
Time:2021-03-12T16:10:43.7053108Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>sr is mandatory. Cannot be empty</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>`

Comment: This error indicates that there's something wrong with your shared access signature token. How are you creating the token?

Comment: I removed one extra question mark from sas_token and not getting that error.

Comment: I added the “?” In the URL thinking your SAS token didn’t have it. Are you able to download the blob now?

Comment: I generated the sas token from azure portal.

Comment: No, I'm getting different error now. `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
`

Comment: I want to upload file there.

Comment: Could you send the code snippet if you have for uploading document in blob storage. I'll be really grateful for that.

Comment: Yeah, that’s right. Is there anything special about the storage account where you want to upload? Is it behind a firewall or inside a VNET or something?

Comment: Sharing settings for networking-

Allow access from - All networks
network routing-Microsoft network routing

And it's free tier account. This is my 2nd day working on Azure. I don't have any knowledge for doing something special.

Comment: Updated my answer with code snippet. HTH.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. It worked.

Comment: Great! I am glad to hear that you're unblocked. Good luck with Azure :).

Comment: `<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The specified resource does not exist.`
Can you help with this :-(

Comment: More than likely you're trying to directly access a blob using it's URL however the blob is in a private container. You will need a Shared Access Signature URL (with at least Read permission) to read the blob. If that's not the case, please post a new question.

Comment: I have posted a new question. Link to question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605732/azure-blob-storage-error-the-specified-resource-does-not-exist